What is this symbol? I found this on the panel of a circuit breaker setup?
I found this symbol in a wiring diagram on an old distribution panel door. What does that cross line on the wire means?
Is it a wire tap on the line?
Certainly, the diagram used the sine wave symbol for fuse and a box with MCB written on it as the symbol for MCB.



The last image: i found this on a google image search and from the writing nearby that cross line, I can see that 3 x 1.5sq.mm. is written, meaning that there are 3 (1.5 sq.mm.) wires being connected to that wire?
Is such a symbol recognised officially by any standard?

The diagonal slash across a line is a common indication to show that the one line represents multiple conductors.  Probably more common in power distribution "single line" diagrams than in electronics.

That certainly helped! Thanks
